# how to store previous number in Java?

Tags: java

hi I'm new to java and having trouble solving this.

```
void setNumber(int inputNumber)
{
    int currentNumber = inputNumber;
    int previousNumber = ??????????

}
```

so if inputNumber is " 2 " , then currentNumber should be " 2 "
and I want to change inputNumber to something else but I want previousNumber to be " 2 " 
and on and on, previousNumber to have one step before currentNumber's new value. 
how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What was the language you worked on prior to Java? You seems to be missing some key concept in programming.

Answer (score 7):

Just store currentNumber in previousNumber before you overwrite it with the new value.

```
int previousNumber = currentNumber;
int currentNumber = inputNumber;
```

First the previousNumber is overwritten by the currentNumber

```
input = 3
previous = 2
current = 2
```

Then the current gets the new number from input number

```
input = 3
previous = 2
current = 3
```

You now have a variable with current's previous value

Comment: Thanks! but if I set previousNumber and currentNumber as instance variable, they are identical :( what would be the solution?

Comment: None of these are _currently_ fields in your implementation, so they don't get saved at all.  Until you do that, there's no "previous" number at all.

Comment: Just declare the variables outside of your method. If you need all the previous values then use an array like @codeMaker has suggested or an `ArrayList` if you do not know how many values you will be reading in.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array of currentNumber
`int[] currentNumber`
so the current index will store the current number whereas the before indexes will point to the previously stored numbers

Comment: This is a non-solution to a design flaw. *Nothing* will get saved if they're left inside this method. Consider correcting your answer to save between method calls.